# Consider $M\times M $ and find for value(s) of $a,M^{-1}=M$

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $M\times M $ and find for value(s) of $a,M^{-1}=M$, Where 
$M=I-avv^T$ and $v\in \mathbb{R^n}$

how to solve this problem here $M^{-1}=(I-avv^T)^{-1}$

Answer (score 0):

Let's first find $M^{-1}$ by trial and error. It seems natural to guess $M^{-1}=I+bvv^T$ for some $b$ (that depends on $a$). We have: $b$ satisfies
\begin{align*}
I&=M^{-1}M=(I+bvv^T)(I-avv^T)\\
&=I-avv^T+bvv^T-abvv^Tvv^T\\
&=I+(b-a-abv^Tv)vv^T.
\end{align*}
Thus, $b=\frac{a}{1-av^Tv}$. It remains to find $a$ such that $b=-a$:
$$
b=-a\implies a=a^2v^Tv-a\iff a(av^Tv-2)=0.
$$
You can fill in the details from here.

Comment: @yurnero....so a=0

Comment: @learner Sure $a=0$ works. But is that the only possibility? You should say something about the possibility $1-av^Tv=0$. The answer here is a hint that helps you start and write the complete solution yourself.